# Problem while copying WidgetCollection in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I have quite a strange problem ,

While copying one `WidgetCollection` from one `FlowPanel` into another one. `Widgets` in `WidgetCollection` are moving instead of copying.Because of this couple of widgets remain in previous Panel.
Here is my code:

```
    final FlowPanel toDelete = getWidgetByID(from);
    final FlowPanel toPaste = getWidgetByID(to);
    final Iterator<Widget> iterator = toDelete.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        toPaste.add(iterator.next());
    }
```

and next version:

```
    final FlowPanel toDelete = getWidgetByID(from);
    final FlowPanel toPaste = getWidgetByID(to);
    final int count = toDelete.getWidgetCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        toPaste.add(toDelete.getWidget(i));// here, i'm getting IndexOutOfTheBounds exception
    }
```

What's wrong here?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a widget to a new panel, it is automatically removed from its previous panel.  There's no super-easy way to get around this. You need to make a new instance of each widget and then add that copy.

If it's just your goal to move widgets from one panel to another, just change `toDelete.getWidget(i)` to `toDelete.getWidget(0)`.  You might also consider just moving the `toDelete` panel itself instead of moving all of its widgets.

Comment: Thanks, `toDelete.getWidget(0)` is working . I have thought,It should work like other `Collections`.